# MVC .net password validation using regular expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a regular expression to validate a password. The conditions are:

1. Password must contain at least two special characters
2. Password must be at least eight characters long
3. Password must be alpha numeric

I'm able to make sure that there are atleast 8 characters, atleast one alphabet, atleast one number and atleast one special character using the below Regular expression:

```
(?=.*[A-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#$%\^&*\(\)\-_+=;:'""\/\[\]{},.<>|`]).{8,32}
```

Only condition i'm not able to get is there must be atleast two special characters (Above Reg exp is atleast one special characters). Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it's an alphanumeric then how come it allows special chars.?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: by alphanumberic, i mean there must be both alphabet and numbers. Only issue is how to make sure that there are atleast 2 special characters.

Comment: for atleast 8, `.{8,}` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only condition i'm not able to get is there must be atleast two special characters.

Make it twice by putting the pattern which was present inside the lookahead inside a group and then make it to repeat exactly two times.

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=(?:.*?[!@#$%\^&*\(\)\-_+=;:'""\/\[\]{},.<>|`]){2}).{8,32}$
```

If you want to allow  atleast 8 characters then you don't need to include `32` inside the range quantifier, just `.{8,}` would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this, this will make sure that the two special characters are appearing continiously

Comment: no, it asserts that the string must contain atleast two special chars. And it won't be continuous. See i make the `.*?` also to repeat.

Comment: there must be 2 special characters, but they might or might not appear continuously one behind another in the input string

Comment: And also `[A-z]` matches also the chars other than `A-Z` and `a-z`. So that i added `[A-Za-z]`